# Early 20th century children's story: children trying to frighten an alcoholic off the bottle using dyed dogs and icicles

Tags: identification-request

Long ago, I read a children's story by an English author who probably pre-dated Enid Blyton and Richmal Crompton, and could be pre-World War I. It concerned some children trying to frighten an alcoholic off the bottle.

Story line: They show him a bunch of Pomeranian dogs dyed pink, blue and green, to persuade him that he has delirium. When he wakes from a stupor, they cluster around him in lab coats and lay icicles on his stomach (where he can't see them), pretending they're scalpels for operating on him. And so on. Rough humour, but very well written.

Would like to read this writer's work again as an adult, but I simply can't remember his/her name. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: It sounds vaguely like E. Nesbit (in _The Wouldbegoods_, say)  but a spot check on Proj Gutenberg did not find me a match.

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try myself.

Comment: @kimchi Hmm, sounds a bit too dark for Nesbit IMO. Hidden icicles pretending to be scalpels? Sounds more like a horror film than Nesbit's light-hearted fun.

Comment: @Randal'Thor You might well be right.

Comment: Yeah, Nesbit was much more positive. This was a bizarre story. Very entertaining, though.

Comment: This sounds vaguely familiar. I trhink it's by Gerald Kersh but I don't know the title and I could be wrong. I wouldn't call him a children's writer though. **How** long ago did you read it? 50 years ago?